# itextSharp show/hide PDFPTable or any other controls

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, dynamicpdf, dynamicpdf-table2

I am generating dynamic PDF using iTextsharp lib. Need to show/hide table in pdf. I did google a lot but no luck. I want to know is it possible using iTextsharp lib or should check the track. Thanks!

Comment: If you create a PDF which shall contain a table, add a table. If you create a PDF which shall not contain one, don't add one.

Comment: @mkl: thanks for suggestions :(

Comment: It may sound harsh but please keep in mind that pdf essentially is a format for generating a fixed document appearance across platforms, not for dynamic behavior.  There are mechanisms to introduce dynamic behavior but they predominantly use pdf only as container for other formats like flash or XFA. And both of those either are already deprecated or are to be deprecated in the next major pdf specification update.

Comment: We can hide/show content using Optional Content in iText(java). I am working on such implementation. If I make any progress I will share the sample code, so that you can work in itextSharp